Check for same attribute in different fields cypress
I have a form which has multiple disabled and enabled fields..
I have this command which is checking for disabled fields:
Cypress.Commands.add("myElementState", (myselector) {
if(myselector) {

   cy.getBySel(myselector).should('be.disabled")
})

I know this one will check for only one element. How can I improve my code so that I can use different testids for the same object
I would like to do something like this:
cy.myElementState(myselector: [("first-element", "second-element", "third-element")]

first-element, second-element and third-element are testids
Thank you

You are passing an array of selectors, so a simple .forEach() repeats your command cy.getBySel(myselector).should('be.disabled").
/// <reference types="cypress" />

Cypress.Commands.add("myElementState", (selectors) => {
  selectors.forEach(mySelector => {
    cy.getBySel(mySelector).should('be.disabled')
  });
})

For Typescript, add a definition to your index.d.ts file where you define the type definitions for Custom Commands,
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {

    getBySel(selector: string, args?: any): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
    myElementState(mySelectors: string[]): Chainable<undefined>;

  }
}



When you use cy.wrap(selectors).each((selector) => { Cypress assumes that selector is a JQuery<HTMLElement> type.

While it works in Javascript, in Typescript you need to "coerce" the type of the parameter like this

but it's not the best way.
Since selectors is an array of strings you should be using the proper string method .forEach().

Hello i have two questions
1- if my command will be as an object how would i put the typings
myTest (object : {
myElementState(mySelectors: string[]): Chainable; })
-- How this will be put please?
2 -secondly why it is highlighting my function and saying:
Prefer for...of instead of forEach.
thank you

cy.wrap can be used to insert your array into a Cypress command chain. This will yield a Chainable<string[]> variable. This can be iterated over using cy.each.
Cypress.Commands.add("myElementState", (mySelectors) => {
  cy.wrap(mySelectors).each((selector) => {
    cy.getBySel(selector).should('be.disabled')
  });
})
...
cy.myElementState(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);


why it keeps highlighting selector saying "
TS2345: Argument of type JQuery is not assignable to parameter of type string" what does this mean please?

What function is giving you that error?

The one that you wrote
